# How to autosize images from array of images using the php?

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with the autosizing of images when I get list of images from directory as an array using this code:

```
<?php   
    if ($handle = opendir('directory_of_images')) {
        while (false !== ($pict = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($pict != "." && $pict != "..") {
                $thumbsp .= '<a href="#'.$pict.'"><image src="directory_of_images'.$pict.'" width="50" border="0" hspace="5" vspace="5" align="middle"></a>';       
                $thump .= '<p id="'.$pict.'" style="height:700px; margin-bottom:200px;"><br><img src="directory_of_images'.$pict.'" width="450px" align="top"></p>';
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Now, I need to resize images with keep aspect ratio. I would like to resize the image, when the image width is greater than the image height, or vice versa.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function getimagesize($filename_of_img). The 0th and 1st array elements of the return value are the width and height. You can then easily compare the width and height